# Failed to load module "glx" (module does not exist, 0)

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, drivers, virtualbox, nvidia

I'm trying out arch for the first time in a virtual box following [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide) guide. All went well and I wanted to install [KDE](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE). According to [these steps](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg) I've picked the nvidia driver suite when running:

```
pacman -Ss xf86-video
```

and ended up having:

```
#pacman -Q | grep nvidia
nvidia-340xx-libgl 340.76-2
nvidia-340xx-utils 340.76-2
```

Running it as a guest machine, required installing the following packages(I'm using the default kernel 4.0.5-1-ARCH):

```
virtualbox
virtualbox-host-modules
virtualbox-guest-utils
```

The required kernel modules are loaded on startup:

```
# cat /etc/modules-load.d/virtualbox.conf
vboxguest
vboxsf
vboxvideo
```

**.xinitrc** contains:

```
/usr/bin/VBoxClient-all
```

and **.Xauthority** is empty. Upon launching X the following output is returned:

[image: x output]

The logs show that there is no compatible nvidia driver:

[image: no nvidia driver]

Now, my best guess is that I shouldn't have picked the nvidia drivers. Unfortunately, I'm unable to remove them through pacman:

[image: unable to remove package]

How may I remove these packages?

**Edit:**

I've managed to install the nouveau drivers but run into another issue: X can't find the "glx" module:

[image: no_glx]

Also when checking the configuration files a "no screens found" error is returned:

[image: x_no_screens_found]

The **xorg.conf** is the default configuration file:

[image: x_conf_1]
[image: x_conf_2]
[image: x_conf_3]

(pastebinit does not work in the guest vb)

Comment: Try deleting xorg.conf, I don't see no reason for you to have it in the first place.

Comment: @ Brean I've deleted both files. The logs are the same however; X can't find the "glx" module.

Comment: Wait, _both_ files? Which ones do you mean? I was talking about `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or possibly the contents of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`. Also, make sure you've gotten rid of any `nvidia-340xx` related packages, and you might want to install `xf86-video-vesa` for it to have something to fall back on.

Comment: @Brean. I have removed the nvidia drivers and also installed vesa. There were two files in my home directory: ~/xorg.conf and ~/xorg.conf.new with the same contents.

Comment: `xorg.conf` in your home directory doesn't affect xorg. Delete `/etx/X11/xorg.conf` and the contents of `/etx/X11/xorg.conf`, reboot and startx again with vesa installed. If the problem persists, post your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: There is no xorg.conf in /etc/X11 only xinit and an empty directory xorg.conf.d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it running; installed plasma desktop package:

```
pacman -S  plasma
```

(more details [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE)) and pointed X to it(appended the following line to ~/.xinit):

```
exec startkde
```

Running **startx** launches KDE.

Answer (score 1):

Some clarifications:

- nvidia-340xx-utils is not the driver itself, it is utilities for the
  (if I've understood correctly) proprietary driver which you haven't
  installed.
- `xf86-video-*` is open source video drivers, of which
  `xf86-video-nouveau` is the nvidia compatible one.
- `pacman -Ss` searches for packages, whereas `sudo pacman -S` installs
  them. Use `sudo pacman -Rs` to remove a package and its dependencies
  not required by other packages.

Your problems should be solved by installing `xf86-video-nouveau` using `sudo pacman -S xf86-video-nouveau`.

Comment: I've managed to install the nouveau drivers but now X is unable to load the glx module(I'll edit the question).